# Sap.m.Table delete button column text

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

my question is simple. Is there an option where I can put a headerText in the delete column?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: answer is also simple: no.

Comment: Alternatively just add a regular column at the end with just a delete button.